# Get non matching records from two tables in yii2

Tags: mysql, join, yii2

How to get non matching records from two or more table in yii2 ?
I have two tables product_lang and product.I want to delete those records which is in product table but not available in product_lang table.
How is it possible?

```
$sub = Product::find()
 ->leftJoin('product_lang','product.id_product=product_lang.id_product')
 ->where('product_lang.id_product<>product.id_product')     
 ->all();
```

It returns blank.
I am not sure that i am doing right syntax or not.
Please help me.

Comment: Try `where(['!=', 'product_lang.id_product' ,'product.id_product'])`.

Comment: No, It returns only matching records.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
 $sub = Product::find()
     ->leftJoin('product_lang','product.id_product=product_lang.id_product')
     ->where('product_lang.id_product is null')     
     ->all();
```

Comment: No it returns blank.

Comment: if you use var_dump($sub) after this query, will it display something? this code work for me. it will find all records in the products table that are not in the product_lang table. maybe the error is in something other.

Comment: Sorry, It returns only the matching records.